# How can I add or remove the sprint's Kanban board columns in Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to do such a thing? I couldn't find any settings about the topic question. I've pointed out the columns I mean in the following pic:

[image]

Also, I selected Scrum for the development process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very common ask to be able to modify the columns of the task board just like you can do on the Kanban board. We have it on our list to add to the product, but we don't have any ETA yet.

It is also tracked by the user voice item [Customize the columns on the Task Board](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/3229015)