# Adding a bugs column to our Kanban board in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

Visual Studio Team Services let us manage our work with a Kanban board (there's an introduction [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/kanban/kanban-basics)). The 'Backlog' column lists the project backlog. We have chosen to include bugs (red) and user stories (blue) in our backlog:

[image: VSTS screenshot, cropped]

I keep loosing important newly added bugs as they are added to the end of the backlog. How do I add a column to our Kanban board listing the open bugs in priority order?

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer from Ewald Hofman to the question [How can I add or remove the sprint's Kanban board columns in Visual Studio Team Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620314/575530) where he notes:

> It is a very common ask to be able to modify the columns of the task board just like you can do on the Kanban board. We have it on our list to add to the product

Ewald goes on to note that there's a User Voice item for this: [Customize the columns on the Task Board](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519/suggestions/3229015), and as of the 10th of May 2016 this appears to have been moved into the planning phase. Yay.